# How to Configure XAML file to MVC 4.0 Control

Tags: asp.net-mvc

XAMl file having various styles such as

```
<Border CornerRadius="100" Background="{DynamicResource GlobalColorBaseBackground}" Margin="0">
  <Border.Effect>
    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="1" Direction="270" BlurRadius="1" Opacity="0.25"/>
  </Border.Effect>
</Border>
<Border CornerRadius="100" Margin="0" Opacity="0.25">
  <Border.Background>
    <RadialGradientBrush>
      <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
      <GradientStop Color="White"/>
    </RadialGradientBrush>
  </Border.Background>
</Border>
```

Comment: Please add a question if you have one

Comment: XAML has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC. Please ask a valid question.